# How do I send and receive email on my top level domain (Postfix)?

Tags: postfix

Maybe someone here knows the answer. I went through various relay access denied postings but i still can't exactly figure out what i have configured incorrectly.

Mail from my terminal to my personal email account works (but it shows `ec2-user@mail.domain.com`, whereas i'd like it to come from `ec2-user@domain.com`. My mail server is called `mail`).

Likewise, when I send mail to `ec2-user@domain.com`, I get this message:

```
May 26 09:17:43 www postfix/smtpd[27620]: connect
    from mail-oln040092067035.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.67.35]
May 26 09:17:43 www postfix/smtpd[27620]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT
    from mail-oln040092067035.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.67.35]: 
    554 5.7.1 <ec2-user@domain.com>: Relay access denied; 
    from=<bla@outlook.com> to=<ec2-user@domain.com> 
    proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR02-AM5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
```

if I mail to the mail. With subdomain it works fine, both from my email client or from the terminal on the host itself. How can I send (and receive) mails from my entire domain? Is it a Postfix configuration thing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a Postfix configuration thingy.  It's [Postfix Basic Configuration](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#mydestination).

> The [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) parameter specifies what domains this machine will
>   deliver locally, instead of forwarding to another machine. The default
>   is to receive mail for the machine itself. See the [VIRTUAL_README](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) file
>   for how to configure Postfix for [hosted domains](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#canonical).

The error `Relay access denied;` suggests forwarding to another machine is used instead of local delivery, so you only have `mail.$mydomain` (possibly from `$myhostname`) in your `mydestination`.

You can check the current configuration with `sudo postconf mydestination` ( `-d` for showing default values). This way it's easier to know the actual value when the configuration file is longer, because:

> When the same parameter is defined multiple times, only the last
>   instance is remembered.
>
> Otherwise, the order of `main.cf` parameter definitions does not matter.

Maintaining email servers is a complicated area. Let me be straight: if you have this kind of problems, you shouldn't do it yourself. Read through [Why You May Not Want To Run Your Own Mail Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server).

> Quick summary: setting up and maintaining your own mail server is
>   complicated and time-consuming, and there are several affordable
>   alternatives—most people will get more value, in the form of saved
>   time, out of using a paid mail service.

Comment: Hi Esa, thank you. I'm an experienced unix and network person, so despite me not being up to date with postfix configuration, i'm sure i can figure it out. I don't want to pay for mail services like mailgun or mailchimp, i dont have the money for it and it seems like something i can do myself. I'm aware of all the pitfalls. I've already cleaned my ip address of all blacklists. Quite frankly i think more people should run their own instead of resorting to commercial mail providers at the first sign of trouble. It might be complicated, but it is not rocket science either. I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i have my own domain included in the : mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain list. Or is order important in that it would take the $myhostname first if it were before the $mydomain ? I probably don't have $mydomain in there separately if it is not configured by default, i will check and change that. Thank you.

Comment: Is that configuration literal? You shouldn't have two `mydestination` lines. _When the same parameter is defined multiple times, only the last instance is remembered._ The second line doesn't contain bare `$mydomain`.

Comment: This is the $mydestination line: mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain

Comment: And this is my "SENDING MAIL" line: myorigin = $mydomain. I restarted postfix but mail still has the from address as www.mydomain.com.

Comment: See also `myhostname` and `mydomain` to be sure they are what they are meant to be.

Comment: yes, myhostname is set the www hostname and my domain is set to the domain.com

Comment: Let me try and refer to my smtp server in wordpress (both on the same host) and send emails from there, and see if that comes from the domain or not. Maybe because i'm using "mail" from the command line it emails by defaults from the host itself. Which brings me to another thing, how do i authenticate on the smtp server for a specific user, do i just create that user and assign a password? (i'm using public and private keys with ssh currently).

Comment: that seems to work, but strangely enough i can do it without authentication. That is..unexpected.